# I Keep getting "error Could not find the following native modules: RNReactNativeOko. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?"

Tags: react-native

I created a react-native using this [package](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library) it is a simple library and what it does is just pops up an alert:

```
import { NativeModules, Alert } from 'react-native';

const { RNReactNativeOkoModule } = NativeModules;

class RNReactNativeOko {

    create() {
        Alert.alert('You need to...')
    }

}

export default new RNReactNativeOko()
export default RNReactNativeOkoModule
```

I then in other to test this module, I packed it using `npm pack` and installed it in a test project with:

```
npm install /Users/sidomexmusicstudio/Desktop/ReactNativeOkra/react-native-react-native-okra-1.0.0.tgz
```

the on running `react-native run-ios` I get the following error:

> error Could not find the following native modules: RNReactNativeOko. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?

Please why is this?

Comment: same issue i am facing..

Comment: @AbhishekTomar i managed to solve this issue,  run `pod init` then `pod install` in the ios folder located in the root directory of your react-native project

Comment: It was useful for me, but I had to run first `pod repo update` and then `pod install`.